# JavaScript data structure question for reporting

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm trying to create a budget headcount variance report in JavaScript (or loadash), and struggling to get the output structure that I need for my reporting.

I have budget array structured as follows:

```
budget = [
 {'id': 1, 'position': "Project Manager"},
 {'id': 2, 'position': "Drafter"},
 {'id': 3, 'position': "Quality Control"}
]
```

A employee array as follows:

```
employee = [
 {'id': 1, 'name': 'Fred R', 'rate': 150 },
 {'id': 2, 'name': 'Adam C', 'rate': 100 }
 {'id': 3, 'name': 'Will P', 'rate': 75 }
 {'id': 4, 'name': 'Tom B', 'rate': 200 }
 {'id': 5, 'name': 'Jay A', 'rate': 175 }
]
```

And, lastly, a link array as follows:

```
link =[
 {'id':1 'budgetId': 1, 'employeeId': 2, 'start': '9/1/22', 'end': '9/20/22'},
 {'id':2 'budgetId': 2, 'employeeId': 4, 'start': '9/5/22', 'end': '9/15/22'},
 {'id':3 'budgetId': 3, 'employeeId': 5, 'start': '9/10/22', 'end': '9/12/22'},
]
```

The output I need looks as follows. I need to show the budgeted positions and all the employees (regardless of if they are linked to a position), and where the employee is linked to the position, then show them on that line (along with the linked start and end date).

| Position | Start | End | Employee |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Project Manager | 9/1/22 | 9/20/22 | Adam C |
| Drafter | 9/5/22 | 9/15/22 | Tom B |
| Quality Control | 9/10/22 | 9/12/22 | Jay A |
| n/a |  |  | Fred R |
| n/a |  |  | Will P |

Does anyone have any help to point me in the right direction? I'm a little lost at the moment on how to approach.

Answer (score 0):

For each employee, find a link, if it exists find its position, then output an object with the requested data.

```js
const budget = [{'id':1,'position':"Project Manager"},{'id':2,'position':"Drafter"},{'id':3,'position':"Quality Control"}];
const employees = [{'id':1,'name':'Fred R','rate':150},{'id':2,'name':'Adam C','rate':100},{'id':3,'name':'Will P','rate':75},{'id':4,'name':'Tom B','rate':200},{'id':5,'name':'Jay A','rate':175}];
const links = [{'id':1,'budgetId':1,'employeeId':2,'start':'9/1/22','end':'9/20/22'},{'id':2,'budgetId':2,'employeeId':4,'start':'9/5/22','end':'9/15/22'},{'id':3,'budgetId':3,'employeeId':5,'start':'9/10/22','end':'9/12/22'}];

const output = employees.map((employee) => {
  const link = links.find((link) => link.employeeId === employee.id);
  const position = link !== undefined ? budget.find((position) => position.id === link.id)?.position : "n/a";

  return {
    position,
    start: link?.start,
    end: link?.end,
    employee: employee.name,
  }
});

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would there be a way to also manage positions which don't have an employee assigned to them? This code would ignore those I believe, as works for the employee array.